# suppress log4j for couchbase messages

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, logging, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

//Suppress(diasble) log4j for couchbase messages i need to use this file how to do it here

```
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>

<!-- To enable JMX Management -->
<jmxConfigurator/>

<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-5level %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!--  <logger name="" level="INFO"/> -->

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not log4j. Its Logback. You can turn it off

```
<root level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>
```

Or set to error level

```
<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>
```

Or if you need to remove console completely just remove reference to the console appender

```
<root level="ERROR">
 <!-- COMMENT OR DELETE THIS LINE <appender-ref ref="console"/> -->
</root>
```

See [Logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html)

Comment: not working i need to remove this from console   15:16:57.129 [Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to mpdbhost/10.0.0.8:11210}] DEBUG c.c.client.CouchbaseConnection - Done dealing with queue.
15:16:57.130 [Memcached IO over {MemcachedConnection to mpdbhost/10.0.0.8:11210}] DEBUG c.c.client.CouchbaseConnection -

Comment: I will update my answer. Try removing console completely then or direct to log file.